# Not sure why my custom post meta field isn't saving

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I'm having trouble getting my custom post meta field to save and I'm not quite sure why. I was following the tutorial located at http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type and had some pretty big difficulty de-coding the special character explosion that happened all over that post... Any help is much appreciated.

```
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("job_location", "Job Location", "location_callback", "job_or_internship", "side", "default");
  add_meta_box("start_date", "Start Date", "start_callback", "job_or_internship", "side", "default");
}

function location_callback(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post_ID);
  $location_callback = $custom["location_callback"];
  ?>
  <label>Job Location:</label>
  <input name="year_completed" value="<?php echo $location_callback; ?>">
  <?php
}

function start_callback() {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post_ID);
  $start_callback = $custom["start_callback"][0];
  ?>
  <label>Start Date:</label>
  <input name="start_callback" value="<?php echo $start_callback; ?>">
  <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
function save_details(){
  global $post;

  update_post_meta($post_ID, "location_callback", $_POST["location_callback"]);
  update_post_meta($post_ID, "start_callback", $_POST["start_callback"]);
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77631/73).

Comment: Where should that be added? I'm assuming in the save_details() function, but am I trying to wrap both update_post_meta()'s in this if? Can you give a little insight into what I should be trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register your save handler with two accepted arguments:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details', 10, 2 );
```

You get two important parameters now:

```
function save_details( $post_id, $post ) {}
```

The first is the post ID, the second the complete post object. Do not rely on a global post object. In some situations it is not available, *bulk edit* for example.

Then use a *nonce* filed in your metabox output to make sure you handle only values sent per your box:

```
echo wp_nonce_field( 'job_location', '_nonce_job_location' );
```

In your save handler validate the nonce with:

```
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_nonce_job_location' ], 'job_location' ) )
    return;
```

During an auto-save request the extra fields are not sent, so do not do anything when `DOING_AUTOSAVE` ist defined:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
```

And test if the user is allowed to edit the current post:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;
```

*After* all these checks you can save or delete the data.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks so much for your help with this!