# Custom wp_editor doesn't update post_content

Tags: save-post, wp-editor, wp-update-post

I'm working on a client's site, creating a staff profile plugin. The issue is that they previously created the profiles as regular posts. I converted all of the staff posts into a custom post types.

In order to customize the post admin I followed [Dipesh Kc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815843/how-to-customize-default-wordpress-editor) to customize the default editor. I wanted to use the existing content for the staff posts, but customize the editor, removing the media uploader and other options.

UPDATE: While I successfully was able to change the default editor settings, and the post content is being displayed in the editor. I hooked `wp_update_post` into the `save_post` hook, thinking that what I'm editing is the `post_content` in a new custom metabox. When I update the post, I basically get a fatal error, memory exhausted warning, though when I check the database, the `post_content` does get updated with my edits.

The relevant sections of my plugin code are included below based on [gicolek's gist](https://gist.github.com/gicolek/4392890) and also by looking at the WP codex page for [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post):

```
public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'meta_boxes' ));
        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'save_bio_data' ), 10, 1);
    }


    // Modify default content editor

    /**
     * Adds a box to the main column on the Post edit screen uses modified editor
     * 
     * @hook add_meta_boxes
     * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box 
     */
     public function meta_boxes()
    {
        global $_wp_post_type_features;      
            //check for the required post type page or post or <custom post type(here article)  
            if (isset($_wp_post_type_features['tn_cstm_people']['editor'])) {
                unset($_wp_post_type_features['tn_cstm_people']['editor']);
                add_meta_box(
                    'tn_cstm_people_bio',
                    __('Bio'),
                    // To address callback function in a class
                    array($this, 'bio_editor_meta_box'),
                    'tn_cstm_people', 'normal', 'core'
                );
            }
    }

    public function bio_editor_meta_box($post)
        {   
            // Use nonce for verification
            wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'tn_cstm_noncename' );


            $settings = array(
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'textarea_name'=>'tn_cstm_bio',
                'tabindex' => '4',
                'teeny' => true
            );

            wp_editor($post->post_content,'tn_cstm_bio', $settings);
    }



    /**
     * When the post is saved, save our customized post data 
     * 
     * @hook save_post
     */
    public function save_bio_data($post_id) {

        // check if we're on the cpt page and if the nonce has been set
        if ( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) or !isset( $_POST['tn_cstm_noncename'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // check if the we're on the custom post page
        if ( !in_array( $_POST['post_type'], array( 'tn_cstm_people' ) ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // if we're doing an auto save return
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return;

        // verify nonce for the safety reasones
        // @see http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tn_cstm_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            return;

        /* Make sure that current user has proper rights to save the post
         *@see Caution! in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post 
          *Otherwise would generate multiple (hundreds of copies of the post)
         */

        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return;


              /* Verify that post type is not set to revision and that $post object needs to be updated
                *http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post
                */

             if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

                // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
                remove_action('save_post', 'save_bio_data');

                // update the post, which calls save_post again

                $data_content = $_POST['tn_cstm_bio'];
                $my_post = array();
                $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
                $my_post['post_content'] = $data_content;

                wp_update_post( $my_post );

                // re-hook this function
                add_action('save_post', 'save_bio_data');
            }


        }
```

Does anyone know why the post_content isn't updating? Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you try to save the content?

Comment: Hmm, currently it's not plugged into any function. I inferred that it would just update when the post is saved.

Comment: I've been looking at the Codex for the documentation for [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post). Do I need to update the "bio" post content and update it with a hook to "save_posts"?

Comment: You have to hook into `save_post` to [save the data](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102360/73). WordPress doesn’t know automatically what to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints toscho. I did take a look at the `save_post` action, and looked up some more documentation. I think that what's going on is that I'm creating a new metabox and custom field initially populated by the `post_content`? And then I'm using `update_post_meta` in the `save_bio_data` function hoooked into `save_post` to finally save the data. Though this hasn't worked either. I updated my original question with my current working code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, now I tried using wp_update_post, and have edited my question appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I have really no time currently. Maybe [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77323/73) can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching and working off of some pointers from toscho, and [some other helpful posts to avoid an infinite loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51363/how-to-avoid-infinite-loop-in-save-post-callback) I managed to figure out a solution. I'll post the code below then briefly explain:

```
// Hook into the actions here
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'meta_boxes' ));
        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'save_bio_data' ), 10, 1);
    }



  // Modify default content editor

    /**
     * Adds a box to the main column on the Post edit screen uses modified editor
     * 
     * @hook add_meta_boxes
     * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box 
     */
     public function meta_boxes()
    {
        global $_wp_post_type_features;      
            //check for the required post type page or post or <custom post type(here article)  
            if (isset($_wp_post_type_features['tn_cstm_people']['editor'])) {
                unset($_wp_post_type_features['tn_cstm_people']['editor']);
                add_meta_box(
                    'tn_cstm_people_bio',
                    __('Bio'),
                    // To address callback function in a class
                    array($this, 'bio_editor_meta_box'),
                    'tn_cstm_people', 'normal', 'core'
                );
            }
    }

    public function bio_editor_meta_box($post)
        {   
            // Use nonce for verification
            wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'tn_cstm_noncename' );


            $settings = array(
                // Removed media upload buttons and added other values here
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'textarea_name'=>'tn_cstm_bio',
                'tabindex' => '4',
                'teeny' => true
            );
            // Define your custom wp_editor here. Use existing post content: $post->post_content
            wp_editor($post->post_content,'tn_cstm_bio', $settings);
    }



    /**
     * When the post is saved, save our customized post data 
     * 
     * @hook save_post
     */
    public function save_bio_data($post_id) {

        // check if we're on the post page and if the nonce has been set
        if ( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) or !isset( $_POST['tn_cstm_noncename'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // check if the we're on the custom post page
        if ( !in_array( $_POST['post_type'], array( 'tn_cstm_people' ) ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // if we're doing an auto save return
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return;

        // verify nonce for the safety reasones
        // @see http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tn_cstm_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            return;

        // make sure that current user has proper rights to save the post
        // @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return;


              /* Verify that post type is not set to revision and that $post object needs to be updated
                *http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post
                */

                // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
                remove_action('save_post', array($this,'save_bio_data'));

                // update the post, which calls save_post again

                $data_content = $_POST['tn_cstm_bio'];
                $my_post = array();
                $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
                $my_post['post_content'] = $data_content;

                wp_update_post( $my_post );

                // re-hook this function don't forget to format as add_action('save_post', array($this, '$function_name'))'
                add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_bio_data'));


        }
```

My problem was taking existing posts and converting them into a custom post type (the client had used regular posts to create a staff directory). I wanted to modify the default editor, rename and simplify it while using the existing post_content.

Basically, I looked at several pre-existing solutions (linked above) and arrived at my own. The important consideration is that I was using `post_content`, though it was now edited through a custom metabox. To make edits, I needed to run updates through the `wp_update_post` function hooked into `save_post`.

However there are issues with an infinite loop being made, so then I needed to unhook and rehook the `save_post` action as made clear in the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post). The final issue was just having the correct formatting for the `remove_action` and `add_action` hooks, taking into consideration that I was calling them within my custom class.